# VSCode Extension does not show contributions

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

When you install my extension, and you click on "Contributions" in VSCode, it only shows a blank page.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnIjB.png)

I have no clue why that is.. the package.json looks fine though..

How can I show the contributions like any other extension does?

Comment: I've noticed this in the latest update (1.23) it appears to be an issue with the update rather than with your package.json file, maybe it will be better to open a GitHub issue, instead. And if you decide to do so, maybe post a link to the issue for future reference :)

Comment: Come to think of it.  @DaGhostmanDimitrov, what github repo would you post the question?  VSCode (https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode)?

Comment: yep the official ones, they are friendly people there so you shouldn't have any issues

Comment: I posted it here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/50454

Answer (score 0):

This was a [bug in VS Code 1.27](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/50454). It is fixed in VS Code 1.28+

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same issue!
I used to create new branches for different lessons learned which were never part of the main branch.

> Merging the branches to main(master) updated my contributions.